# Retrieve first insert Id from a query and insert into multi query is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been working with this project, now am stuck where i have to insert the id of the first query of which it identifies the relations of that table to others, i want the id of the first query to be saved as a variable and then be inserted into the following queries

I've tried to set value to be used but its not working, as i want all these to work in one multi-query, down here are some code of the queries

```
$query = "INSERT INTO guests (
user_id, 
first_name, 
last_name, 
nationality, 
status,
sign_up) 

VALUES (
'$user_id', 
'$first_name', 
'$last_name', 
'$nationality', 
'$status',
NOW());";

$query = "SELECT @last_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();"


$query .= "INSERT INTO bookings (
user_id, 
guest_id,  
coming_from, 
going_to, 
date_in, 
date_out, 
sign_up)

VALUES (
'$user_id', 
@last_id,  
'$coming_from', 
'$going_to', 
'$date_in', 
'$date_out', 
NOW());";

$query .= "INSERT INTO preference (
guest_id, 
prefer, 
alergy, 
sign_up)

VALUES (
@last_id,  
'$prefer', 
'$alergy', 
NOW());";


$query .= "INSERT INTO rooms (
user_id, 
guest_id,
room_number, 
room_type, 
room_price, 
sign_up)

VALUES (
'$user_id', 
@last_id,  
'$room_number', 
'$room_type',
'$room_price',
NOW())";

  if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query))
  {
    echo "Guest Received successfully!";
  } else {
    echo "Failed! Data input error!";
  }
}
```

i expected it to fetch the first query guest id and insert it into @last_id column, Kindly any ideas?

Comment: @Zak The code isn't trying to retrieve the ID, it's just trying to use it in subsequent queries.

Comment: I think the code should work. You can also use `SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: In general, I recommend against using `mysqli_multi_query()`, it makes things more difficult. Just perform multiple `mysqli_query()` calls. This will also allow you to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables.

Comment: What is it inserting into the `guest_id` column instead of the new guest ID?

Comment: yes, i want to use the first query guest id to insert into the two last query, let me do @Barmar

Comment: I can't see any reason why the code you've written shouldn't work.

Comment: You need to do better error checking. You're just checking whether the first query succeeded, you need a loop to check them all. See the documentation of `mysqli_multi_query`, it has examples.

Comment: thanks guys, it's working though am shifting to prepared statements instead of substituting variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On occasion, I've had to use this:

```
SELECT `auto_increment` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
```

or

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = your_tablename' AND table_schema = DATABASE( ) ;
```

Perhaps that will work for you

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html

https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php